# How can I send raw Json using Kafka Confluent C# client?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a consumer application that expects JSON something like this: `{"timestamp":1554138000,"level":"first","message":"abc"}`. But Confluent Message object seems to be a key value pairs of strings. I assume, the message KV pairs are internally serialized as json. But how can I ensure that it does not put double quote for timestamp value? Is there a way to pass raw JSON as message?

Answer (score 0):

By passing null string for the key and Json string in the value, I was able to produce the Json expected by consumer application